# Custom Code Panels preview in InstallAnywhere?

Tags: java, swing, awt, installanywhere

Is there a way to preview custom code panels in InstallAnywhere? Non-custom code panels can be previewed using the InstallAnywhere IDE. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this for these panels. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: It is not a programming question.

Comment: The custom panels uses swing to build its UI, Im wondering if there is some sort of a hack to preview it in eclipse for example. The idea came from this article http://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/pdf/archive/ia_create_cust_code_panel_eclipse.pdf. Unfortunately the custom panels (that was given to me) were not made using the visual editor and was coded manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just got InstallAnywhere 2017; according to Flexera's SP1 release note they are supporting custom panels preview (IOJ-1759620):
http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installanywhere2017/IAReleaseNotes_en.htm

In case you're using older IA versions, you may implement your custom panels on any java swing editor such as eclipse or netbeans (I prefer netbeans since it has an oobt support for swing editor).